# unexpected jquery event behaviour from within contained div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am seeing unexpected behaviour on a small HTML widget ive recently created. Three successively embedded divs each one has a marker and a menu which show up on entry into the div and hide on exit. The marker is intended to track the vertical mouse position. Problem here is that the mouseover event fires only when the mouse is over the marker and not when the mouse over the containing div.

http://jsfiddle.net/laurencefass/f47a7a2r/

```js
$( ".outer, .inner, .middle" )
   .mouseenter(function(e) {
       $(this).children(".content:first").show();
  $(this).parents().children(".content:first").hide();

       $(this).children(".marker:first").show();
       $(this).parents().children(".marker:first").hide();
   })
   .mouseleave(function(e) {
       $(this).children(".content:first").hide();
       $(this).parents().children(".content:first").show();

       $(this).children(".marker:first").hide();
       $(this).parents().children(".marker:first").show();
   })
   .mouseover(function(e) {
    $(".content", $(this)).html("left = " + e.pageX + " right = " + e.pageY);
    var marker = $(this).children(".marker");
   marker.offset({top:e.pageY - marker.height()/2, right:0});});
```

```css
.outer, .middle, .inner {
    font-size:0.8em;
    position:absolute;
    border:5px solid black;
    background-color:lightgray;
    text-align:center;
}

.outer {
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    width:80%;
    height:500%;
}

.middle {
    top:5%;
    left:20%;
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
}

.inner {
    top:5%;
    left:30%;
    width:40%;
    height:60%;
}

.content {
    background-color:aliceblue;
    min-height:2em;
    min-width:50px;
    display:none;
}

.marker {
    height:50px;
    width:5em;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    margin-right:2px;
    display:none;
    color:white;
    fontsize:0.8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="content">outer menu</div>
    <div class="marker">widget</div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="content">middle menu</div>
       <div class="marker">widget</div>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">inner menu</div>
            <div class="marker">widget</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you trying to update marker position on mouse move? if yes then you need to use mousemove

Comment: thank you. this solves the problem. though it doesnt explain why the jquery code above is responding to $(".marker").mouseover events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done much easier just using CSS. You can use this functionallity for your widgets too.

```
.outer:hover>.content,
.middle:hover>.content,
.inner:hover>.content{
    display: block;
}
```

Then you can strip out your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$( ".outer, .inner, .middle" )
   .mouseover(function(e) {
       var marker = $(this).children(".marker");
       marker.offset({top:e.pageY - marker.height()/2, right:0});
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f47a7a2r/10/)**

If you only want to show the widget of the element hovered you have to use jQuery, Furthermore you would probably use mosemove() event to have it at the mouse position all the time.

```
$( ".outer, .inner, .middle" ).mousemove(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var marker = $(this).children(".marker");
    marker.eq(0).show();
    marker.offset({top:e.pageY - marker.height()/2, right:0});
});

$( ".inner, .middle" ).mouseenter(function(e) {
    if($('.marker', $(this).parent()).eq(0).length){
       $('.marker', $(this).parent()).eq(0).hide();
    }
});

$( ".outer, .inner, .middle" ).mouseleave(function(e) {
    if($('.marker', $(this).eq(0)).length){
       $('.marker', $(this).eq(0)).hide();
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f47a7a2r/11/)**

Comment: this doesnt solve the problem with the .mouseover function which is appears to react only to .marker events which you can see by including the line: $(".content", $(this)).html("left = " + e.pageX + " right = " + e.pageY);

Comment: also trying to apply the css selectors to the markers does not disable to correct parent marker. so all 3 switch on at once. i think the js is necessary to hide the parent marker.

Comment: I gave you an jQuery solution where only the desired widget is visible

Answer (score 0):

my expectation: a rhs "floating" widget to track the vertical position of the mouse and be visible only as long as the cursor is within scope of the marker's container.